# BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60

Tags: flutter, gradle

Please help me to out this problem. I am trying to run my first project on my real device but I am getting this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_firstapp\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Which jdk are you using? I think 16. If possible use JDK 13

Comment: Thank you, brother. Now It is working.

Answer (score 1):

Use JDK 13 instead of JDK 16. Major minor version error in java means jdk and class compile version mismatch.